# Add defined component programmingly in Dart Angular

Tags: angular, dart, components

I want to add a new element which is styled in a component defined by me before. I have tried like this:

```
document.querySelector('#chatitem')
..children.add(new Element.html("<material-chip>"+message+"<\/material-chip>"));
```

However, it does not work. How should I add this? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: what version of AngularDart are you using?

Comment: The version is v2.

Comment: There is no angular dart v2, see https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular#-versions-tab-

Comment: Thanks very much. I created a same post in our discussion group. Please help me have a check there if possible dart-discuss@.